# ADODB Firebird 2.5 HowTo set Charset to ISO8859_1?

Tags: php, firebird, adodb, interbase

I have a php script which is using a sql select to get data and puting this into a text formfield for editing which then in an external php file will get written back into the firebird DB.

In the main file i have set the HTML chartset to ISO8859_1 and everthing works fine.

In the external save file i am not able to set it. So i have weird characters in my firebird db when saving to it.

```
$conn = ADONewConnection('ibase'); 
      $conn->Connect('localhost:C:\DATA.FDB','sysdba','masterkey');
```

I have read the ADODB manual and several other pages and tried everything i could imagine withing 8 hours with no luck.

EDIT: i am sorry, i completly mixed up 2 files so i did post before the non ADODB version, abouve is the streamlines ADODB version. So how do i extent this to change the chartset=

Comment: I found this in the manuall, but now idea where to put it:If you have special characters such as /:?_ in your dsn, then you need to rawurlencode them first:

         $pwd = rawurlencode($pwd);

         $dsn = "mysql://root:$pwd@localhost/mydb";

         $dsn2=rawurlencode("sybase_ase")."://user:pass@host/path?query";

Comment: How do i set the dialect btw.?

Answer (score 0):

The character set is fourth parameter of the [`ibase_connect` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ibase-connect.php), so

```
$dbh = ibase_connect($host, $username, $password, 'ISO8859_1')
```

should do the trick.

Comment: it works which means i dont get errors anymore, but its not changing the weird charackter problem. I type in ä and get back Ã¤.

Comment: What is the character set of the database (or the `comment` field in case it has different characterset than the DB's default) and what is the code you use to read the value back and show it?

Comment: Here is that data of the field: Field:Blob, Subtype:Text, Charset: ISO8859_1, Collate: ISO8859_1  This is the code: 
    $db = ADONewConnection($databasetypef); 
    $db->Connect($serverf, $userf, $passwordf); 
 $sql = "select .......
  $result = $db->Execute($sql); 
 if ($result === false) die("failed");

Comment: I haven't used ADO with PHP so I don't have any experience with it, sorry. But with little googling I found this (http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm#connect_ex): `$dsn = 'firebird://user:pwd@localhost/mydb?charset=ISO8859_1'; $conn = ADONewConnection($dsn);` You have to repalce relevant parts in the dsn string, of course.

Comment: thats the dns call i think thats a different synthax.